# Imprlementing Angular 2 services

Tags: angular, service

I'm trying to have each page of my app set the title tag in the head.
I've followed several examples as best I can to set it up as a service, but it's not behaving as expected.

title.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { TitleService } from '../../../services/title.service';

@Injectable()
export class  {


    constructor() {
    };  


    appName = "My App";

    public setTitle(newTitle: string) {
        console.log("!!!");
        this.setTitle(this.appName + " - " + newTitle);
    }
}
```

login.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';

export class BaseLoginComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private titleService: TitleService
        ) {
    }

    this.titleService.setTitle('Login!');
```

Instead of getting 'MyApp - Login!' I get simply 'Login!'

So, strangely, I **am ** able to set the title, I am just somehow bypassing the service.

It never calls setTitle().

What's more, I wanted to see if title.service was even being loaded, so I tried to insert a **console.log("loaded..?");**. It throws a bunch of errors on that line - mostly expecting semi-colons.

Comment: Is that infinite recursion in setTitle function?

Comment: Code updated. That piece of code in app.component seems unnecessary anyway, so I've removed it.

Comment: @DaveC426913 you didn't even include the class name in your code. Is it overriding Angular's default title service?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I see where I'm going awry. There is an *existing* setTitle service; I don't need to make my own.

It's literally as simple as:

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@NgModule({
    providers[
        Title
    ]
})
```

login.component.ts:

```
import { Title }     from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(private title: Title){}

this.title.setTitle('MyApp - Login');
```